# Combining Polylines on Google Static Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to make a static map request with multiple polylines. It works fine when I have a single polyline, but when I add them together I don't get the intended results. Specifically, I'm trying to highlight adjacent street blocks.

Polyline 1 works fine:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=400x400&path=weight:10%7Cenc:{d`pEnpypUc@_@u@Q
```

Polyline 2 works fine:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=400x400&path=weight:10%7Cenc:c``pEtjypUi@fAu@zA[j@mAzB
```

But combined, I get this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=400x400&path=weight:10%7Cenc:{d`pEnpypUc@_@u@Q%7Cc``pEtjypUi@fAu@zA[j@mAzB
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me (separate the polyline specifications):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=400x400&path=weight:10%7Cenc:c``pEtjypUi@fAu@zA[j@mAzB&path=weight:10%7Cenc:{d`pEnpypUc@_@u@Q
```

(You need to add "&path=weight:10%7Cenc:YourEncodedPolylineHere" for each polyline)

Comment: To simplify: You need to add "&path=weight:10%7Cenc:YourPolylineHere" 
for each polyline.

Comment: Thanks, added that to the answer.